# Mapping supply and demand between two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have 2 different dataframes 
df1 - for demand
df2 - for supply jobs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Part':list('aaa'),
 'QtyNeeded':[2,2,2],
  })

 df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Job':['j1','j2'],
 'Qty':[4,2],
  })
```

the result I was looking for is the mapping between df1 and df2 and assigning jobs to parts based on qty

```
Part  QtyNeeded  Job
a     2          j1
a     2          j1
a     2          j2
```

Tried merge and other techniques but couldn't think of any quick solution

Comment: any assumption? what if there is no exact match? this calls for more in-depth analysis.

Comment: @EdwardAung df2 is only created because of df1 requirements. As you can see a total of demand (df1.QtyNeeded) matches with a total of supply(df2.Qty).  The confusing part is they are not one to one, total will always be the same but the number of jobs can vary.

Comment: Sorting each descending and arbitrarily splitting (in a loop) using two pointers will do? It may not be very pythonic (or panda-nic) but it will work. The loop will look similar to a merging two sorted lists.